# Footnotes defined with \newfootnoteseries don't work

Tags: errors, memoir, bugs

I'm having trouble with new footnotes defined using `\newfootnoteseries`. The following MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newfootnoteseries{P}

\begin{document}

\footnote{Test1}
\footnoteP{Test2}
\footnoteP{Test3\ss}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Footnote test]

i.e., the first `\footnoteP` has no text; the second just the `\ss`. The second also results in the error

```
/home/zach/tex/cwrc/sandbox/footnotetest.tex:8: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \OT1\ss 
l.8 \footnoteP{Test3\ss}
                        
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

/home/zach/tex/cwrc/sandbox/footnotetest.tex:8: Extra \endcsname.
\@nameuse #1->\csname #1\endcsname 
                                   
l.8 \footnoteP{Test3\ss}
                        
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
```

I'm using pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 and memoir 2023/08/21 v3.8.1

I think the bug is on l. 8696,

```
      \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces\@nameuse{foottextfont#1 ##1}%
```

The `##1` should be outside the `}`

Comment: Thanks for the report. Fixed in development.

Answer (score 6):

Nasty bug! The macro `\@footnotetextP` ends up with

```
\@nameuse {foottextfontP #1}
```

in its body, instead of

```
\@nameuse {foottextfontP}#1
```

so the footnote text is treated as part of a macro name, instead of being typeset, and the macro is undefined, so `\relax` is used instead. However The `\ss` bit triggers an error and is eventually typeset.

The error is at line 8696 of `memoir.cls`

```
      \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces\@nameuse{foottextfont#1 ##1}%
```

which should be

```
      \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces\@nameuse{foottextfont#1}##1%
```

For your case you can patch the generated macro:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newfootnoteseries{P}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@footnotetextP
  {\@nameuse {foottextfontP #1}}
  {\@nameuse {foottextfontP}#1}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\footnote{Test1}
\footnoteP{\unexpanded{Test2}}
\footnoteP{\unexpanded{Test3\ss}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

File a bug report.